# How to create method for age calculation method in android

Tags: java, android

I want to write a method to calculate the age from the birth date, is the logic correct and how to write it in android Java:

```
public int calculateAge(String birthday){ 
 // consider that birthday format is ddmmyyyy;

 String today = SystemDate(ddmmyyyy);
 int bDay = birthday(1,2).toInteger;
 int bMonth = birthday(3,4).toInteger;
 int bYear = birhtday(5,8).toInteger;

 int tDay = today(1,2).toInteger;
 int tMonth = today(3,4).toInteger;
 int tYear = today(5,8).toInteger;

 if (tMonth == bMonth){
     if (tday>= bDay){ 
        age = tYear - bYear;
      else 
        age = tYear - bYear - 1;}
 else
   if (tMonth > bMonth) {
       age = tYear - bYear;
   else 
       age = tYear - bYear - 1;}
 }
 return age;
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is my solution to the problem:

```
/**
 * Method to extract the user's age from the entered Date of Birth.
 * 
 * @param DoB String The user's date of birth.
 * 
 * @return ageS String The user's age in years based on the supplied DoB.
 */
private String getAge(int year, int month, int day){
    Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    dob.set(year, month, day); 

    int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
        age--; 
    }

    Integer ageInt = new Integer(age);
    String ageS = ageInt.toString();

    return ageS;  
}
```

I used a [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html) to get the input values required here. This method, together with the date picker, is specifically to get the user's DoB and calculate their age. A slight modification can be made to allow for String input(s) of the user's DoB, depending upon your specific implementation. The return type of String is for updating a TextView, a slight mod can be made to allow for type `int` output also.

Comment: I used a DatePicker to get DOB,too, but I convert it to string in order to store it in the database (SQLite), and every time I need the age for calculation I return the dob as an argument, so I add the substring method to get the year, month and day.

Comment: I built this solution using bits and pieces of answers on SO, I believe the `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` came from a answer that pointed to www.coderanch.com. Enjoy!

Comment: @Kingsolmn im sorry to say but your algo is wrong,your are not checking the month case

Comment: @MuhammadBabar how do you mean?

Comment: your solutions fails when current month is equals to d.o.b month  but current day is less than d.o.b day, please see my answer below

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying now. However, the case you are describing is why I opted to use the `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` field. Just a different approach to the same solution is all. The best approach should be determined, in part, by the implementation. That and personal preference and style.

Comment: Not working for this date : 27-11-1989 , I am getting 26 year but actually i am 27 year old

Answer (score 16):

This works Perfectly.....

```
public int getAge(int DOByear, int DOBmonth, int DOBday) {

        int age;

        final Calendar calenderToday = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentYear = calenderToday.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int currentMonth = 1 + calenderToday.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int todayDay = calenderToday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        age = currentYear - DOByear;

        if(DOBmonth > currentMonth) {
            --age;
        } else if(DOBmonth == currentMonth) {
            if(DOBday > todayDay){
                --age;
            }
        }
        return age;
    }
```

Comment: It's work fine...above all example are giving wrong age when you enter 27-11-1989, My age is 27 but it shows 26...

Comment: Yes. other answers are wrong on current birth month. The age change affects once the only birth month over. But this code from the day.

Comment: this must be accepted answer...works perfectly even in current month bday too..all above answers doesnt give me accurate answer when bday is in current month.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example android age calculation that you should be able to work from:

```
    public int getAge (int _year, int _month, int _day) {

            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            int y, m, d, a;         

            y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            cal.set(_year, _month, _day);
            a = y - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            if ((m < cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                            || ((m == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) && (d < cal
                                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) {
                    --a;
            }
            if(a < 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age < 0");
            return a;
    }
```

Comment: @Jon Egerton the link is disable change it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fully tested and working code

Below is an example using date picker dialog

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int mBirthYear, int mMonthOfYear, int mDayOfMonth) 
    {
            mAge = year - mBirthYear;

            if( (mMonthOfYear == month && day < mDayOfMonth) || ( month < mMonthOfYear) ) 
            {
                mAge--;
            }

            String years = getString(R.string.years);

            etAge.setText(mAge+years);      

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Due to the existence of a new(er) date and time library it is not recommended to use `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` anymore. The only exception should be a situation where you have to involve considerably large amounts of legacy code.

So… here is the modern way using `java.time` (Java 8+).

**Java**

```
public int getAge(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    return Period.between(
                LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth),
                LocalDate.now()
            ).getYears();
}
```

**Kotlin**

```kotlin
fun getAge(year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int): Int {
    return Period.between(
                LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth),
                LocalDate.now()
            ).years
}
```

Both snippets need the following imports from `java.time`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period
```

See also [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Since there's [API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) in Android now, there's even no/little need for a backport like
[ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) which only supported API levels 26 and above in Android.

API desugaring makes (a subset of) `java.time` directly available to API levels below 26 (well, not really down to version 1, but will do for most of the API levels that should be supported nowadays).

Answer (score 0):

None of the posted solutions worked for me. So, I worked my own logic and got this, which works 100% for me:

```
 Integer getAge(Integer year, Integer month, Integer day) {
     Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
     Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

     dob.set(year, month, day);
     int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

     if(month == (today.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) && day > today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
         age--;
     }

     return age;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will provide you age in the most accurate way possible

```
public static String getAgeFromLong(String birthday) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    Calendar dobCal=Calendar.getInstance();
    dobCal.setTime(sdf.parse(birthday));

    Calendar diffCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    diffCal.setTimeInMillis(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - dobCal.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

    String ageS = "";

    int age = diffCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1970;
    //Check if less than a year
    if (age == 0) {
        age = diffCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        //Check if less than a month
        if (age == 0) {
            age = diffCal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
            //Check if less than a week
            if (age == 1) {
                age = diffCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
                ageS = (age - 1) + " Days";
            } else {
                ageS = (age - 1) + " Weeks";
            }
        } else {
            ageS = age + " Months";
        }
    } else {
        ageS = age + " Years";
    }

    return ageS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime) , also works for KMM.

The birthdate in ISO format: `2003-02-22`

```kotlin
fun calculateAgeFromBirthdate(birthdate: String): Int {
    val birthdateParts = birthdate.split("-")
    val birthYear = birthdateParts[0].toInt()
    val birthMonth = birthdateParts[1].toInt()
    val birthDay = birthdateParts[2].toInt()

    val currentMoment = Clock.System.now()
    val currentDate = currentMoment.toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()).date
    val currentYear = currentDate.year
    val currentMonth = currentDate.monthNumber
    val currentDay = currentDate.dayOfMonth

    var age = currentYear - birthYear
    if (currentMonth < birthMonth || (currentMonth == birthMonth && currentDay < birthDay)) {
        age--
    }
    return age
}
```